# Updating UI Components of One Stage Based On Event in Another Stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have two `Stages`, for instance, Stage1 and Stage2. Stage1 has a `ListView` and a `Button`. OnPressing button present on Stage1, I open a dialog i.e. Stage2. Stage2 has `TextField` and a `Button`. If I enter a string in TextField and click on the button, I close the previous Stage1.
Now, I want to update the ListView once I click on stage2 button.

I don't close Stage1 when I press button to open the dialog.

I use showAndWait function on stage2

```
window.showAndWait();
```

and close it using

```
stage.close();
```

Above is a part of the stage. There are other components which I would like to refresh based on the button press in stage2.

Could anyone please suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: The `showAndWait();` method will block until the second stage closes, so all you need to do is put the code to update the first stage immediately after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @James_D's advice and "refreshed" my `ListView`. I intended to add an item to `ListView` and update it based upon `Button` event.

I handled the button event in my `controller` and called refreshListView() if the item was sucessfully added to the list. Basically, I realized that the control is returned to the Stage1 controller once the stage2 is closed. So I wrote below code:

```
    @FXML
    private void handleAddNewItem(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        boolean flag = mNewBox.display();
        if(flag==true){
            refreshListView();
        }
    }

    public void refreshListView() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list = singleton.getFiles();

        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
        itemsListView.setItems(items);
    }
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are using FXML or just coding.

But in any of these two ways the approach is the same:

you need to have both of your stages in variables. Then add an `onAction` event listener where it will trigger your stage 2 to be `stage2.showAndWait()`.

as for the textfield and the List. You need to add to that list with as simple `arrayList.add();` then pass the new list to your listView `FXController.ObservableArrayList(arrayList)` then to update or "refresh" that listView it is kind of uncertain lately since there is no method to "refresh" but by setting `listView.setVisible(false);` and `listView.setVisible(true)` has done the trick!!

If you want it to be "automatic" you would have to add all that on your `onAction` event!

Good Luck

If you had code I would have provided a better example but I think I have addressed all the questions.